# IIS 8.5 sometimes does not return static files

Tags: asp.net, iis, less, owin, keep-alive

I have noticed that sometimes IIS 8.5 does not return static files (*.less and *.js) if they are included into html page.
Browser sends request do download them and continue spinning forever. That is illustrated on following image:
[image: captured requests by fiddler]
After receiving page (request #4) browser tries to download styles for that page and sends request for it (#5) which hangs forever.

Interesting thing, if I replay the same request using Fiddler (#2) - I will get the response (304 or 200) with no delay. Also, I can restart this particular app (not whole IIS) using IIS Manager and response will be send to hanged request (#5). Also disabling header "Keep-Alive" will prevent such hanging, but this can reduce performance. The hanging is not persistent but happens very often.

Question is what can cause such hanging? If you have any thoughts please share them and I will check.

UPD: I also noticed that each request have reached the server but hanged in OwinHttpModule:
[image: ISS: hanged requests]

Comment: If you can capture network packets at server side with Wireshark you might dive deeper. Only the client side capture is usually not enough.

Comment: @LexLi, I tried Wireshark but it works very deep for me. I want to capture requests, but it captures network packages and I cannot understand what they mean.